# Image exists but doesn't show

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an application that simulates the windows desktop. My assets folder contains an Icons folder that contains all sorts of .ico icons which are all set to "Content". When I build my program, the assets folder is also copied with all the .ico inside.

It uses an XML to create the desktop view and I just added the functionnality so that anyone can add their own icons.

However, the icon I added outside the compilation phase (after building) seems to be found by C# and doesn't spit any errors, however I can't see anything in the actual view. What is happening?

Here's my code:

```
if (File.Exists("assets/icons/" + this.IconName))
        {
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\Icons\" + this.IconName, UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\Icons\error.ico", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

And here's an image of the view, you can see that DME doesn't show anything, not even the cross that appears when an image errors out or doesn't exist.

[image: Desktop View]

Comment: It looks a bit odd that you construct the file name twice, `"assets/icons/" + this.IconName` and `@"\Assets\Icons\"  + this.IconName`. It may also be possible that the Uri uses a different base directory for a relative path than File.Exists does. What happens if you try to load the BitmapImage from a FileStream?

Comment: The code you posted is just loading an image into memory, where's the code that draws it?

Comment: @AdamVincent icon.Source = bitmapImage;
            icon.Width = bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 40;
            icon.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);

Comment: @Clemens The first function simply checks if the file exists, the others actually constructs the image.

Comment: Sure. You still construct the path twice without any reason. Better construct it once and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Your `File.Exists` uses forward slashes, and your `new Uri` uses backslashes, this may cause an issue.

Comment: @Jaxi That's not an issue. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think the problem is that File.Exists uses filesystem while a relative Uri on BitmapImage tries to load the image from your application resources,
so you have to specify an absolute Uri.</s>

You could do something like this

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Assets\Icons\" + this.IconName, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: While this may work better than a relative Uri, the explanation is nonsense. You don't have to use absolute Uris because images are "loaded from application resources". You use absolute Uris because you load images from absolute file paths.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your comment, you're totally right. I did some more researching and in case i got it right when you set the `BitmapImage` as `Source` of an image control the image control sets the `BaseUri` of your BitmapImage which by default is a pack URI (that was what i meant with "application resources"). The problem was that i didn't know where the "magic" happens and falsely thought `BitmapImage` does it.